# How do I connect Autocad Map 3D to SQLite database with SaptiaLite extension and export map to the database?

Tags: database, sqlite, geometry, spatial, autocad

I have a map of a floor of a building in Autocad Map 3D and I want to connect to a .sqlite file created with the SpatiaLite GUI and insert all the geometry into that database. I tried connecting to this file, but I can not make a successful connection with the source file.

My intention is to send the spatial objects created in AutoCad Maps 3D to the SQLite database. I want the database to hold the entire map in a table. If you have any other methods they are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

An AutoCAD drawing database is not a conventional database so it will not transfer directly to a conventional database like sqlite.
One way to accomplish this would be to develop an AutoCAD plugin to read the objects out of the dwg file and write their data to your sqlite file.
If you need to do this from a stand-alone app (outside of AutoCAD) you will need a library that can read dwg files and the spatial objects you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use FDO to make a connection, see the following links:

- [To Create a Data Store for SQL Server Spatial](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-map-3d/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/MAP3D-Use/files/GUID-65EAA28F-4956-4C1F-9946-76F7035088F3-htm.html)
- [To Bring In Features from SQL Server](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-map-3d/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/MAP3D-Use/files/GUID-9FFB75EB-DE06-49E8-813B-93CC81085004-htm.html)

As mentioned by [@mohnston](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33535980/4838205), the pure geometry data stored as AutoCAD entities cannot be "connected", but you can write a plugin to enforce such a connection.